# AS3 - Can't access properties or methods of a MC child that has been added in script

Tags: actionscript-3, addchild

I am still a bit of a beginner at AS3, so bear with me, please.

I have created a loop to instantiate tiles on a board.  In the following example, "Gametiles" is an array containing objects of class "Tile" which is a class that extends MovieClip.  "Game" is a MC that I added to the stage in the flash developing environment.

```
for(var i:uint=0;i < Gametiles.length;i++){
    var pulledTile = Gametiles[i];
    var tilename:String = "I_Tile_" + pulledTile.grid_y + "_" + pulledTile.grid_x;
    var createdTile = new InteractiveTile();
    pulledTile.addAnims(createdTile);
    Game.addChildAt(pulledTile, 0);
    Game.getChildAt(0).name = tilename;
}
```

The above code works - but with a tricky problem.  If I did something like the following:

```
trace(Game.I_Tile_1_3.x);
```

I get "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties."
However, I am able to access theses children in the following manner:

```
var testing = Game.getChildByName("I_Tile_1_3")
trace(testing.x);
```

This method is a bit cumbersome though.  I really don't want to have to create a var and call getChildByName every time I want to interact with these properties or methods.  How can I set up these children so that I can access them directly without the extra steps?

Comment: Strong != Loose :) Design decisions...

Answer (score 0):

use the sqare brackets.

```
Trace(Game["I_tile_1_3"].x);
```